# why do i get the syntax error "'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Tags: python, nlp

```
# import Sastrawi package
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory
# create stemmer
factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()

def stemming(text):
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split()]
    return text
data['abstrak'] = data['abstrak'].apply(stemming)
data['judul'] = data['judul'].apply(stemming)
data.head()
```

On the marked line of code,  text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split()],  I get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

When I remove that line from the code, the same error appears at the next line of code, again for no apparent reason.

On the marked line of code,  text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split()],  I get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

When I remove that line from the code, the same error appears at the next line of code, again for no apparent reason.

Comment: `stemming()` is being called with an argument that is a list.

Comment: `stemming` is called with the values in `data['abstrak']` - at least one of those values is a list. Since you haven't posted a working example, we don't know what your data is. You could `print(data['abstrak'])` before the error to see what you've got.